# Count number of rows with at least one value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df like this:

```
a   b   c   d
1   1   1   1
2   2   3   NA
3   NA  NA  2 
4   NA  2   NA
5   NA  NA  NA
```

Is it possible to get a count of how many rows doesn't have non missing values on all variables, so for example here it will return 4 as the rest of the rest have at least one none NA value on some of it's variables.

Comment: Shouldn't "a count of how many rows have non missing values on all variables" return 1 for your example data (the first row) ? Maybe you need to explain the logic more clearly.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo already edited the question

Comment: Are you neglecting column `a` from calculation? So `sum(rowSums(!is.na(df[-1])) > 0)` ?

Comment: *"how many rows doesn't have non missing values on all variables"* Do you mean how many rows have at last one `NA` entry? E.g. `sum(is.na(rowSums(df)))`?

Comment: No.  On this example the answer should 4. You need to exclude the a var from the calculations since that one is the ID number

Comment: @EGM8686 `sum(is.na(rowSums(df)))` returns 4. So is that what you're after? Your problem statement is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is clear now that we want to ignore column `a` from calculation. Here are few ways:

Using `rowSums`

```
sum(rowSums(!is.na(df[-1])) > 0)
#[1] 4

#OR

sum(rowSums(is.na(df[-1])) != (ncol(df) - 1))
```

Using `apply`

```
sum(apply(!is.na(df[-1]), 1, any))

#OR

sum(!apply(is.na(df[-1]), 1, all))
```

Using `filter_at` from `dplyr` filters the row based on condition but we can use `nrow` to get the number of rows which satisfies our requirement.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  filter_at(-1, any_vars(!is.na(.))) %>% nrow
```